# jQuery adding class to only one anchor instead of all

Tags: jquery, function, foreach, each

I have this function:

```
$containing = jQuery('#test a').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).text().substring(0,2) == "Ba";
});

if ($containing.length > 0) {
    $containing.first().addClass('testtt');
}
```

This adds the `class` to the first anchor it finds, but that's not what I want. I wanted to give the class to all the `anchors` containing Ba... I tried replacing `first` with `each`, but nothing happened at all. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `.first()`, then it will be applied to all the objects in the jQuery array, not just the first.

```
$containing = jQuery('#test a').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).text().substring(0,2) == "Ba";
});

if ($containing.length > 0) {
    $containing.addClass('testtt');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `.first()`.  Chaining in jQuery allows most functions to be applied to all of the selected elements.

```
$containing = jQuery('#test a').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).text().substring(0,2) == "Ba";
});

if ($containing.length > 0) {
    $containing.addClass('testtt');
}
```

Comment: @user1770896 Glad I could help.  You will notice that if you `console.log($containing)` it is an array of jquery objects.